# sort array using array_unique from external XML (CDATA)

Tags: php, xml, sorting, cdata, array-unique

I can't manage to sort an array alfabetically.
It's an array with cities that I get from an external XML.

The XML looks like this, and it's the node `localidad` I am trying to sort.

```
<parada>
    <id>506</id>
    <localidad>
        <![CDATA[ Alvor ]]>
    </localidad>
    <parada>
        <![CDATA[ Alvor Baia Hotel (Bus Stop Alvor Férias) ]]>
    </parada>
    <lat>37.1296</lat>
    <lng>-8.58058</lng>
    <horasalida>05:40</horasalida>
</parada>
```

The relevant code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($viajes);
foreach ($xml->parada as $excursion) {
  $newParadasarray[] = $excursion->localidad;
}
$newParadasarray = array_unique($newParadasarray);

foreach ($newParadasarray as $parada) {

  if (strpos($parada, 'Almuñecar') !== false)
                  echo '<option value="Almuñecar">Almuñecar</option>';

  if (strpos($parada, 'Benalmádena') !== false)
                  echo '<option value="Benalmádena Costa">Benalmádena Costa</option>';

  if (strpos($parada, 'Estepona') !== false)
                  echo '<option value="Estepona">Estepona</option>';
  etc.
}
```

I have tried with `sort()` and `array_values()`.

This is the output of `print_r($newParadasarray)`:

```
Array (
  [0]  => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
  [1]  => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
  [2]  => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
  [4]  => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
  [9]  => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
  [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
  [20] => etc.
```

Comment: `print_r($newParadasarray)` shows you what?

Comment: It gives like this:
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [20] => 
etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with DOMDocument you could simply do this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$array = array();

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName("localidad") as $localidad) {
    $array[] = trim($localidad->nodeValue);
}

$array = array_unique($array);
sort($array);
```

Comment: That was very interesting, no idea that could be done that way, nice and clean.

Comment: Finally managed to get it work, with some changes,this is the code:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($viajes);
$newParadasarray = array();
$nodelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("localidad");
foreach($nodelist as $localidad) {
$newParadasarray[] = $localidad->nodeValue;
}
$newParadasarray = array_unique($newParadasarray);
sort($newParadasarray);
  foreach ($newParadasarray as $parada) {

Thanks, again

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your assigning a SimpleXMLElement into the array, instead you want the content of the element, so just change the line...

```
$newParadasarray[] = $excursion->localidad;
```

to

```
$newParadasarray[] = trim((string)$excursion->localidad);
```

The cast `(string)` takes the text content and `trim()` removes the extra whitespace around it.

I am assuming that you have multiple `<parada>` elements, so that `$xml->parada` is returning the correct data.

Comment: Thanks, Did not work, and yes correct data is returned

Comment: Some more information would be useful.  What does `print_r($newParadasarray);` after the extract look like?

Comment: It prints this:
Array ( [0] => Torremolinos [1] => Benalmádena [2] => - [4] => Almuñecar [9] => Nerja [14] => Málaga Capital [20] => Torrox [31] => Torre del Mar [57] => Rincon de la Victoria [93] => Cádiz [94] => Fuengirola [119] => Mijas Costa [131] => Marbella [176] => Estepona [192] => Sabinillas )

However Salmans solution below worked fine and I will use that. Thanks a lot

Comment: OK no problems, but the output looks exactly as I would expect it to so not sure what your problem was.